# Может ли RegLoadKey возвращать код 32 из-за того, что занят реестр а не файл .dat?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, реестр

Использую `RegLoadKey`. Возвращает код 32, который, согласно [winerror](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/debug/system-error-codes--0-499-), означает, что процесс не может получить доступ к файлу, т.к. этот файл занят другим процессом.

Вопрос: под "файлом" здесь подразумевается только файл, передаваемый в аргумент `lpFile` ([описание функции](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winreg/nf-winreg-regloadkeya)) или же, если какой-то процесс занимает нужную ветку реестра, эта ошибка тоже имеет место быть?